# How do I make it go in diagonal directions?

Tags: c++

I have code that I already have four basic directions (Up, Down, Left, Right). However, I want to have them go in diagonal directions as well, so it will add up to eight directions. How would I do that? What I see from it, I basically have to have two directions change at the same time, but I don't know how to do that.

Code:

````
// problem with backtracking using stack 

#include <cstring> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <stack> 

using namespace std;

#define N 4 
#define M 5 

class node {
public:
    int x, y;
    int dir;

    node(int i, int j)
    {
        x = i;
        y = j;

        // Initially direction  
        // set to 0 
        dir = 0;
    }
};

// maze of n*m matrix 
int n = N, m = M;

// Coordinates of food 
int fx, fy;
bool visited[N][M];

bool isReachable(int maze[N][M])
{
    // Initially starting at (0, 0). 
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    cout << '[' << i << ':' << j << ']';
    stack<node> s;

    node temp(i, j);

    s.push(temp);

    while (!s.empty()) {

        // Pop the top node and move to the 
        // left, right, top, down or retract  
        // back according the value of node's 
        // dir variable. 
        temp = s.top();
        int d = temp.dir;
        i = temp.x, j = temp.y;

        // Increment the direction and 
        // push the node in the stack again. 
        temp.dir++;
        s.pop();
        s.push(temp);

        // If we reach the Food coordinates 
        // return true 
        if (i == fx and j == fy) {
            return true;
        }

        // Checking the Up direction. 
        if (d == 0) {
            if (i - 1 >= 0 and maze[i - 1][j] == 1 and
                !visited[i - 1][j]) {
                cout <<'['<< i - 1 << ':'<<j << ']' ;
                node temp1(i - 1, j);
                visited[i - 1][j] = true;
                s.push(temp1);
            }
        }

        // Checking the left direction 
        else if (d == 1) {
            if (j - 1 >= 0 and maze[i][j - 1] == 1 and
                !visited[i][j - 1]) {
                cout << '[' << i << ':' << j-1 << ']' ;
                node temp1(i, j - 1);
                visited[i][j - 1] = true;
                s.push(temp1);
            }
        }

        // Checking the down direction 
        else if (d == 2) {
            if (i + 1 < n and maze[i + 1][j] == 1 and
                !visited[i + 1][j]) {
                cout << '[' << i + 1 << ':' << j << ']' ;
                node temp1(i + 1, j);
                visited[i + 1][j] = true;
                s.push(temp1);
            }
        }
        // Checking the right direction 
        else if (d == 3) {
            if (j + 1 < m and maze[i][j + 1] == 1 and
                !visited[i][j + 1]) {
                cout << '[' << i  << ':' << j + 1<< ']' ;
                node temp1(i, j + 1);
                visited[i][j + 1] = true;
                s.push(temp1);
            }
        }

        // If none of the direction can take  
        // the rat to the Food, retract back  
        // to the path where the rat came from. 
        else {
            visited[temp.x][temp.y] = false;
            s.pop();
        }
        //system("pause");
    }

    // If the stack is empty and 
    // no path is found return false. 
    return false;
}

// Driver code 
int main()
{
    // Initially setting the visited 
    // array to true (unvisited) 
    memset(visited, false, sizeof(visited));

    // Maze matrix 
    int maze[N][M] = {
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    // Food coordinates 
    fx = 2;
    fy = 3;

    if (isReachable(maze)) {
        cout << "Path Found!" << '\n';
    }
    else
        cout << "No Path Found!" << '\n';

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Take a sheet of squared paper (each square standing for a `N,M` position), a pencil and do it there first.

Comment: Be careful not to walk outside your maze as well.

Answer (score 0):

By combining the conditions you already have... You have the following for checking the second dimension:

```
if (j + 1 < m and maze[i][j + 1] == 1 and !visited[i][j + 1])
```

If you want to increment both at once you would do something like:

```
 if (i + 1 < n and j + 1 < m and maze[i + 1][j + 1] == 1 and !visited[i + 1][j + 1])
```

Since you have 4 diagonals, you would do similar checkings for the other 3 diagonals. Be careful with copy and paste not to forget to increment/decrement both i and j.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a board, with row 0 and column 0 in the upper left corner.

Also, assume the present position is at <row, column>.

There are 8 locations relative to the present position (unless you are near the edge of the board).

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+  
| row - 1, column - 1 | row - 1, column + 0 | row - 1, column + 1|  
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+  
| row + 0, column - 1 |     row, column     | row + 0, column + 1|  
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+  
| row + 1, column - 1 | row + 1, column + 0 | row + 1, column + 1|  
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Before making a move, check the validity of the next move.
The next move would be based on the above table.